# Message when too short attribute will work for number field validation in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a LWC Lightning Input to allow 10 digit number for the field.

```
<template if:true = {objMap.Test__c.Test__Number__c.visible}>
 <lightning-input class="slds-m-bottom_medium" data-id="Test__c.Test__Number__c" value={objMap.Test__c.Test__Number__c.value} name="ERP" type="Number" label={label.ERP}  message-when-too-short={label.Max10digits} maxlength="10"  onchange={handleinputchange} required={objMap.Test__c.Test__Number__c.required} disabled={readonlyMode1} read-only={readonlyMode1}></lightning-input>
 </template>
```

I am using the attribute message-when-too-short to thorw error below 10 digits value.But it is not working.My suggestion This attribute is  working  for only characters or number field also.If i have to use number field what attribute should i have to use, when usere enter below 10 digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`message-when-too-short` is used with `minlength`, and works only for `email`, `password`, `search`, `tel`, `text`, and `url` types.

To specify a minimum value for a `number` type, use `message-when-range-underflow` and `min` instead:

```
<lightning-input 
  type="number" 
  min="1000000000" 
  message-when-range-underflow="Please enter at least 10 digits"
  ...>
```

Note that you should make sure the `type` attribute is lowercase. `Number` is not in the documentation, but `number` is.